# Ansible: How to take key values from a yaml file, and insert them into another text file in a loop-like fashion?

Tags: loops, ansible

I have 2 files, one of an indeterminate but consistent format (which could be some sort of html format...), and one of a yaml format. I want the values of the yaml file to be input into the other file. I've used include_vars for the yaml input file and can reference/manipulate them properly. It's the output file, and the value replacement process which is the problem.

The output file cannot be fully re-written, and should instead be edited in place since it has other information in it other than the line with the values to be replaced which must stay untouched.

There are over 100+ values in each file, and the idea is to have ansible "match up" the name of the line from the input file with the one of the same name in the output file.  THEN, take the value from the input file, and replace the output file's value with it.  My hope is to not have to do this with 100+ tasks, and instead loop it somehow.
This is especially helpful if more key/value pairs are added in the future, such that I don't have to manually code in new ones each time.

The output file could have it's values initially set to anything, but they must be cleanly replaced with the values from the input file.

Initial Examples:

Input file/variables in yaml format:

```
---
 client_host_port: 6000
 first_eth_port: eth55
 this_value_for_stuff: 233
 this_value_for_stuff_2: 133
```

Playbook task to import the input file which works wonderfully:

```
     - name: Full import of the config.yaml file so that the desired variables are populated.
       include_vars:
         file: ~/config.yaml
         name: config_vars
```

Output file examples in the indeterminate/oddhtml format:

```
[network_settings]
 
<client_host_port             value="fillwithyamlfilevalue"/>
<first_eth_port               value="fillwithyamlfilevalue"/>
Purpose: To define for the system the first ethernet port to use.
<this_value_for_stuff         value="fillwithyamlfilevalue"/>

[alternate_settings]
<this_value_for_stuff_2       value="fillwithyamlfilevalue"/>
Note: value 2 is a backup value.
```

Now an example of the desired state afterwards:

Input file once again (this only ever changes if manually changed):

```
---
 client_host_port: 6000
 first_eth_port: eth55
 this_value_for_stuff: 233
 this_value_for_stuff_2: 133
```

Output file desired end state:

```
[network_settings]
 
<client_host_port             value="6000"/>
<first_eth_port               value="eth55"/>
Purpose: To define for the system the first ethernet port to use.
<this_value_for_stuff         value="233"/>

[alternate_settings]
<this_value_for_stuff_2       value="133"/>
Note: value 2 is a backup value.
```

That's the basic idea, except the real files will have many more key/value pairs, though in the same format.  The workflow is that if the service people's tool populates the input file with new values, the playbook with these task(s) could be run manually or via cron to instantly populate it across servers in the fleet.

Thanks in advance!

**Note, I had another post similar to this one which was answered beautifully, however, the requirements changed after I implemented it, and thus this question now exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a jinja template of the entire output file like so:

(/mytemplates/foo.j2)

```
[network_settings]
 
<client_host_port             value="{{ client_host_port }}"/>
<first_eth_port               value="{{ first_eth_port }}"/>
Purpose: To define for the system the first ethernet port to use.
<this_value_for_stuff         value="{{ this_value_for_stuff }}"/>

[alternate_settings]
<this_value_for_stuff_2       value="{{ this_value_for_stuff_2 }}"/>

[other_settings_that_must_not_change]
<dont_change_me       value="3"/>
```

As you can see, the values you want to replace are surrounded by curlies in the jinja fashion for denoting a variable, with the corresponding variable name from your yaml file. Then you'd have an Ansible task to render the template and overwrite the target file:

```yaml
- name: Template a file to /etc/file.conf
  ansible.builtin.template:
    src: /mytemplates/foo.j2
    dest: /etc/file.conf
    owner: bin
    group: wheel
    mode: '0644'
```

When Ansible renders the template it will replace the curlies with your variable values from your yaml file and leave the rest of the template alone.

> The output file cannot be fully re-written, and should instead be edited in place since it has other information in it other than the line with the values to be replaced which must stay untouched.

The output file can be fully rewritten, as long as your jinja template has all the values which must stay untouched hard coded in it alongside the variables.

You can also do for loops in jinja templates:

```
[network_settings]
{% for key, value in my_dict.items() %}
<{{ key }}            value="{{ value }}"/>
{% endfor %}
```

Yaml would look like this:

```yaml
---
my_dict:
 client_host_port: 3
 first_eth_port: 4
...
```

This would render two lines, one for each item in the above yaml dict.

Comment: Zendritic, ah I didn't know I could use variables from an import even in a jinja2 template, that helps a lot.  I will try that myself for sure, but do you, or anyone else know of a way to get it to loop through the values in the input.yaml file such that I don't need to hardcode each key from it in the template?

Comment: @viscosity You can do a for loop inside of a jinja template. I believe ansible will still render this the way jinja has it documented here: jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#for. I edited my above response to show how.

Comment: I will try the loop and see if it works, as I suspected a loop could somehow be done within the template.  It's good to know that it can be, and if it does I can mark this as the answer.  I will let you know.

Comment: Yup I finally found the way I want to do it, and this helped me get to the answer and essentially was... just had to be broken into multiple pieces.  Either way, good to learn about how to work with Jinja2 templates and loops.  Thanks Zendritic!